# Review the message for suspended from triage - change "Unsalvageable" to "flag"

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues, review-suspension

I have been suspended from triage and part of the suspended message looks like this:

[image: Image of unsalvageable message]

Please change it to

> Choose the "flag" action for questions that should be closed...

I performed the review today (2020 Nov 1) and was also suspended today (2020 Nov 1). after the change of the triage

Comment: This message is part of a [moderator script](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/UserReviewBanHelper.user.js). I have pinged the author and [filed an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues/91).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The text in that message is not part of Stack Overflow. It's from a [userscript that a moderator uses](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/cf2015030349b7a25db4a3a0f872f4a4157e0ea1/UserReviewBanHelper.user.js#L50) to assist with moderation.

Martijn Pieters has raised [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues/91), although if you really wanted, you could fork the repository, change the text in your fork and make a pull request to merge it back into the master.